# Creating array names programmatically in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm a noob programmer and am wondering how to create array names using a list of words from another array.

For example, I would like to take this array:

```
array = ['fruits','veggies']
```

and turn it into something like this:

```
fruits = []
veggies = []
```

What is the best way to do this in Ruby?

Here is my shot at it, where I failed miserably:

```
variables = ['awesome', 'fantastic', 'neato']

variables.each do |e|
  e = []
  e << [1, 2, 3]
end

puts neato
```

Comment: It's for a SERP checker. A user enters their keywords and then when I search Google with the list of keywords, I want to be able to take the serps and put them in an array named for the keyword that was just searched. And then I can take each array and check for where their url is located in the list. I hope that explains it well enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that your array might contain a value that matches the name of a local variable or method and that's when the pain and confusion starts.

Probably best to build a hash of arrays instead:

```
variables = ['awesome', 'fantastic', 'neato']
hash = variables.each_with_object({ }) { |k, h| h[k] = [ ] }
```

Or, if you don't have [`each_with_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001516):

```
hash = variables.inject({ }) { |h, k| h[k] = [ ]; h }
```

Note the argument order switch in the block with [`inject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001494) and that you have to return `h` from the block.

This way you have your arrays but you also protect your namespace by, essentially, using a hash as little portable namespace. You can create variables on the fly as Jacob Relkin demonstrates but you're asking for trouble by doing it that way. You can also run into trouble if the elements of `variables` end up being non-alphanumeric.

Answer (score 5):

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
arr.each do |a|
  self.instance_variable_set(('@' + a.to_s).intern, [1,2,3])
}

puts @a #[1,2,3]
```

Comment: When I run it with that, I get an undefined method or variable when I attempt to print one of the new arrays.

For example, I tried:
puts awesome.to_s
and I get that error

Comment: @Melanie, See my updated answer. You should be able to get that to work.